# Show that the function is Lebesgue measurable to apply Fubini's theorem

Tags: measure-theory

Let $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a Lebesgue measurable function. I proved using Fubini's theorem that 
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|f(x)| dx = \int_{0}^{\infty} m(\{x: |f(x)| \geq t\}) dt
$$

However this requires that $h(x,t)=1 \ \text{if} \ 0 \leq t \leq |f(x)|$ to be Lebesgue-measurable function. How do I prove this ?

Edit: $m$ is one-dimensional Lebsgue measure. $h$ is the function to which I am applying Fubini's theorem.

Comment: So you mean that this requires that $m(\{x: |f(x)|>t\})=1$?

Comment: Is it easy if $f$ is simple? If so, try a simple function approximation.

Comment: @Stef No; the problem amounts to integrating an indicator function $h$ over all of $\mathbb{R}^2$, and writing down two different formulas for the integral of this function (one with each possible order of the iterated integrals). The question is, is the set in question a Lebesgue measurable set?

Comment: @Ian. Ok, thank you.